# How to test a regex match to a single character?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to test a regex against a single character within a string using the following code:

I've attempted to do this using the String.prototype.match method as well as with the RegEx.test method, to no avail.

An example of an input would be "HELLO124".
I want the console to log with every uppercase letter, but not with anything else.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let regex = /[A-Z]/;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (regex.test(str[i])) {
      console.log('Match!');
    }
  }
}
rot13('HELLO124');
```

I am never reaching the 'Match!' output.

Comment: Give an example of what inputs you'd expect to produce which outputs.

Comment: What's in `str`? Your regex will only match uppercase letters, so maybe you just need to add the case-insensitive flag (i.e. `/[A-Z]/i`)

Comment: @Marc An example of an input would be "HELLO124". I want the console to log with every uppercase letter, but not with anything else.

Comment: It works in my console.

Comment: Your code already works. If you want to log the letter you matched, just log `str[i]`.

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet to your question with the same code and your example. Click Run code snippet and you'll see it log "Match!" the expected number of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by p.s.w.g, the regex `/[A-Z]/` matches only uppercase letters.

To match any letter (I assume this is what you mean by "a single character"?), use `/[A-Za-z]/`, or `/[A-Z]/i` (i for case insensitive).

**Edit:** now that you clarified your problem, I tested your snippet, and it is working for me. Perhaps you are not passing the string correctly to the method.

Try console logging the string inside the method to make sure.

```js
rot13("HELLO1234");

function rot13(str) {
    let regex = /[A-Z]/;  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
      if(regex.test(str[i])){
          console.log('Match!');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify in the initial post, but n example of an input would be "HELLO124". I want the console to log with every uppercase letter, but not with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For one upper case:

```
/[A-Z]{1}/g
```

For one lower case:

```
/[a-z]{1}/g
```

For one lower or upper case:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{1}/g
```

For one lower or upper case:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{1}/g
```

For one anychar (includes, everything basically) case:

```
 /.{1}/g
```

For one either lower, upper or number

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,1}/g
```

You can try your regexper [HERE](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B1%2C1%7D%2Fg):) is a reaaaaally useful tool.